# Why str.substr(0,4) is not a function?

Tags: jquery

I'm making a script with jQuery and I got the following number `7.2387`. All i have is get only `7.23`, for this i've written the following code:

```
var str = 7.2387;
var shorter = str.substr(0,4);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
all.js?55:92 Uncaught TypeError: str.substr is not a function
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (all.js?55:92)
    at HTMLSpanElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLSpanElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

And my whole script stops working, it works only when I remove the `substr(x,y)` function. I made sure to have jquery updated. What's wrong?

Comment: Because `str` is not a string and doesn't have a `substr` method.

Comment: If you want a number with a certain number of decimal places, use `toFixed()`.

Comment: And how can i do it with numbers?

Comment: You could use `Math.round(str * 100) / 100`

Comment: @barmar in this case, `toFixed(2)` returns 7.24

Comment: Used @Barmar s function and worked perfectly :-)

Answer (score 17):

Because `str` is not a string and doesn't have a `substr` method. You have to convert it to a string first.

```js
var str = 7.2387;
var shorter = String(str).substr(0, 4);
console.log(shorter);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `substr()` method extracts parts of a **string**, beginning at the character at the specified position, and returns the specified number of characters.

But in your case, `str` variable is not a string. If you want to get specific sized representation of your variable (numeric value), you may use `toFixed()` method which converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals.

```js
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed(2);

console.log(n)
```