# Javascript extract last numbers from Math.random

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

So I'm trying to do a script for Photoshop with javascript and I can't get the last 6 number from a Math.random.

I tried using the same code as in Strings with "randomID.substr(randomID.length - 6);" or "randomID.substr(-6);" but that didn't work.

```
var kodi = 'FJ0B';
var randomID = Math.floor(Math.random() * (999999999999 - 100000000000 + 1) + 100000000000);
var lastSix = randomID.toFixed(-6);

var kontrataLayer = (kodi.charAt(0) + lastSix);
```

Math.floor works fine, I need it with 12 digits for another function.
Thank you.

Comment: `randomID.toFixed(-6)` makes zero sense, it should even throw a range error. _At least_ go read up on the methods you are trying to use … // `(""+randomID).substr(-6)` is an easy & quick way to convert your number to a string first, and then take the last 6 characters.

Comment: You can convert it to string and then convert it back if required. Eg: var randString = String(randomID).substr(String(randomID).length - 6)

Comment: about .toFixed(-6) i just saw one answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572930/why-str-substr0-4-is-not-a-function

Comment: I'm new on javascript, don't be so harsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
var randomIDString = randomID.toString();

var lastSix = Number(randomIDString.substr(randomIDString.length - 6));
```

For `substr` to work you need to convert the number to a string. Maybe that's why it didn't work for you earlier?